# Prove $2^{(h(x)-5)}+3x$ is not equal to $\sin(x)$

Tags: calculus

I am working on my CalcII class and have been doing reasonably well so far. I'm now stuck with this exercises:
Given $$ h(x): \mathbb R+0 \rightarrow \mathbb R , h(x+\Delta x) > h(x) \,  \forall x \in D$$
Prove that:

$$2 ^ {h(x)-5} + 3x \neq \sin(x) \,\forall x\geq 0 $$

I am really at a loss here: I hate to say this, but I cannot see where to start here. I can see $h(x)$ is strictly increasing; however, I fail to see how this could help me to prove the inequality.

I'll be very grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction so I can work it out.

Lots of thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $$h(x+\Delta x)>h(x) \forall x $$
tells us $h'(x) >0$ and therefore that $h(x)$ is strictly increasing. You saw this. 
Now, we have that $$x\in \Bbb R \to \sin x \not> 1$$
and that $$0<x<1 \to \sin x \approx x$$
Which implies $$3x>\sin x$$

All you need for the $2^{h(x)-5}$ is that:

$$\alpha \in \Bbb R \implies 2^\alpha > 0$$

Comment: Why is $h$ differentiable?

Comment: I'm just using the definition of the derivative from first principles.

Comment: In the statement, $\Delta x$ is not quantified, so we don't know that the inequality holds for all $\Delta x$'s.  Even if it were universally quantified, the inequality would hold for a jump discontinuity, which isn't differentiable.

Answer (score 6):

For $x > 0$, $3x > \sin x$. Then we add something positive to the side that's already larger...

At $x=0$, we're instead comparing (zero + positive) to (zero), and $3x+2^{\text{whatever}} > \sin x$. Combine the two parts, and $2^{h(x)-5} + 3x > \sin x$ for all $x\ge 0$.

Comment: Of course, @Ross Millikan. I considered using $\ge$ signs instead, but wrote the strict inequality version instead. The full solution is probably a little simpler with the $\ge$ signs, because then we don't have to handle zero separately.

Comment: Point made. I've added to the answer to cover that case.

Comment: Thanks.  I had already upvoted, so can't do it again.

Answer (score 0):

Recall from geometric constructions that $\sin x \leq x$. Also, $x \leq 3x < 3x + 2^y$ because $2^y > 0$ for all $y\in \Bbb R$. Combine these and you're done.